# Does a high-dimensional matrix $M$ built from a low-dimensional matrix $k$ inherit spectral radius and irreducibility?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, tensor-products

Let $k=(k_{a,b})_{a,b=1,\dots,n}$ be an *irreducible matrix* with *non-negative integer entries* $k_{a,b}\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.
Moreover suppose:

1. $k_{ab}=0\ \Leftrightarrow\ k_{ba}=0\,$, and set $E:=\{(a,b)\,|\, k_{ab}>0\}=\{(a,b)\,|\, k_{ba}>0\}$;
2. for every $a=1,\dots,n$ the sum on the $a^{th}$ line is  $k_a:=\sum_{b=1}^n k_{a,b}\geq 2$.

Then I have the following (sparse) matrix $M$ indexed by $E\times E$ :

$$ M_{(a,b),(c,d)} \,:=\, \begin{cases} k_{ab}-1\, & \text{if }a=d,\,b=c \\
k_{ac}\, & \text{if }a=d,\,b\neq c \\
0\, & \text{if }a\neq d
\end{cases}$$

for every $(a,b)\in E$, $(c,d)\in E$.

The entries of $M$ are still non-negative (by definition of $E$).

- Is $M$ still irreducible?
- Is the spectral radius of $M$ related to the spectral radius of suitable $n\times n$ matrices, like the matrices $k^{(b)}=(k^{(b)}_{ac})_{a,c=1,\dots,n}$ for $b=1,\dots,n$ defined as follows:
  $$k^{(b)}_{ac} \,:=\, \begin{cases} k_{ab}-1\, & \text{if }b=c \\
  k_{ac}\, & \text{if }b\neq c
  \end{cases} \qquad ?$$